# Wait for event listener load

Tags: javascript

I have this portion of code with some action executed on load.

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        //Something other
    }, false)
```

When I execute this function

```
this.searchUnit= function (product, supplier, invoice, status) {
            window.location.href = "units.html";
            this.clean();
            title = document.getElementById("viewTitle");
            title.textContent = "Unità";
            sessionStorage.removeItem("product");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("supplier");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("invoice");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("status");

            //Something other...
        }
```

I need all the operation of event Listener function ended before execute "this.clean()"

How can I do this?

Comment: Call `searchUnit(...)` at the end of the load event listener.

Comment: on which load? what is your context ?

Comment: @Barmar searchUnit(...) has some params. How could I pass them in a call at the end of load event?

Answer (score 0):

If every other thing is synchronous in your code then probably put all the things that you want to do after the event listener in a setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(functionToBeCalledAfterEventListener,0);
```

This will make sure to execute the function after all the things in queue are executed.